Is there a way to see if an excel workbook contains shapes using either openpxyl or by looking at the underlying XML?
I have thousands of excel workbooks and need to create a list of which ones contain shapes that might have text (ie a text box). How would I use either openpyxl or the underlying XML to generate a list of all shapes with text? I tried using both xlwings and pywin32, but those libraries both parse the shapes too slowly to be useful.
Current slow code:
for shape in ws_xlwings.shapes:
    if shape.type == "text_box" or shape.type == "auto_shape":
        try:
            str_cell_value = shape.text.lower()
            str_cell_value_upper = shape.text
        except: #shape might not have text
            continue


Please post a relevant xml sample of a shape.

Here's a POC on how to handle excel as zip files, extract drawing xml and detect text boxes. It's probably faster than parsing the whole spreadsheet.
from zipfile import ZipFile
from lxml import etree

def main():
    z = ZipFile('/home/luis/tmp/shapes.xlsx')
    drawings = [ drw for drw in z.filelist if "drawings" in drw.filename.split('/') ]
    for drw in drawings:
        with z.open(drw.filename) as sstr:
            ssdata = sstr.read()
            
            tree = etree.fromstring(ssdata)
            ns = {"xdr": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing",
                  "a": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", 
                  "r": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
                  }
            shapes = tree.xpath('//xdr:txBody[preceding-sibling::xdr:spPr]/a:p/a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces = ns)
            
            print(shapes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Result for a simple xslx with 2 sheets and 1 shape per sheet
['Text box 2']
['Sheet2 ellipse text 3']

To just detect text boxes
shapes_cnt = tree.xpath('count(//xdr:txBody[preceding-sibling::xdr:spPr]/a:p/a:r/a:t)', namespaces = ns)

Based on https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/howto/reading-xlsx-files-with-python.html

Thank you so much! This not only identifies the shapes, but also pulls in the relevant text, so perfect. Two follow-up questions 1. Is it possible to also pull in the name of the shape? 2. Is it possible to look for cells highlighted a certain shade due to conditional formatting? I am assuming the answer to this is no since it would need to re-calculate the cell to see which conditional formatting option would apply, but wanted to check

Glad it worked. 1. tree.xpath('//xdr:spPr/a:prstGeom/@prst', namespaces=ns) should get the name of the shape like ellipse 2. Not sure without an xslt sample but probably hard to get. BTW, was performance improved? Curious :-)

Its so much faster! Xl wings was taking a couple sends per file just to open it, but this worked almost instantly

If you want to find out which drawings are on which worksheet, you'll need to traverse the worksheet relationships.
